# QML - Not able to get width,height etc in "On Completed"

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I need to get width and height of a Rectangle in **`Component.OnCompleted`** handler but if i print the same i am getting some unknown values, Following is the code:

**[EDIT-1]** - Added more code.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("test")
    flags:  Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Rectangle{
        id:rectParent
        width:parent.width * 0.75
        height: parent.height * 0.70
        Rectangle{
            id:rectChild
            width:parent.width * 0.75
            height: parent.height * 0.70
            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("Width=",width) //prints "0" .
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How To get width, height in `onCompleted`?

Comment: Why do you need it in `Component.onCompleted` ? Can't you do it in `onWidthChanged` ?

Comment: Than you would get it upon resize again.

Comment: You could just decide to keep the first non zero width. Or maybe getting it upon resize again is needed. I asked to figure why pra7 need to use non declarative code.

Comment: @GrecKo Usually I use percentage to calculate the size of a control, But what do you mean by declarative code?

Comment: GrecKo's question is: "Why do you need the `width` within the signal handler `Component.onCompleted` at all?" Usage therein is usually non-declarative.

Comment: @derM ,I want to create a component when rectChild's onCompleted signal is emitted and thus height and width is necessary to pass as an property inside createObject().

Comment: That is exactly the content of GrecKo's question: Why do you want to use non declarative code? Why don't you create the objects declaratively?

Comment: @derM if I need to create a component but that should take half of the width what would be the best approach?

Comment: @pra7: Of course you can use `createObject()`. But you need to mind the difference between declarative programming, where you only say: "It Shall Be" and imperative programming, where you say: "do this, then do that, and than [...]". In QML, good style is, if you avoid using imperative programming (JS code beyond a single expression). There are objects (e.g. `Loader` or `Repeater`) to dynamically and declaratively create objects. Of course, this is not possible at any time.  If you are more interested in it, maybe *GrecKo* would answer a new question on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to start again:
Your problem is a misconception, what *hides* behind `parent`.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true
    Rectangle {
        id: someRect
        width: parent.width * 0.7
        heigth: parent.height * 0.7
    }
}
```

Here you assume, `parent` for `someRect` is `appWindow`, and therefor, `parent.width = appWindow.width = 600`. **This is wrong**

The parent of `someRect` can't be `appWindow`, as `appWindow` is not of type `Item`. In fact, `someRect.parent === appWindow.contentItem`, so `width: parent.width => width: appWindow.contentItem.width`.

The problem is, that the width of the `contentItem` is `0` when created, and will reseized to `appWindow.width` only after creation.

This means, that `someRect.width` is also `0` until the width of `appWindow.contentItem` has been resized to `600` - which won't happen until `Component.onCompleted` is executed.

The solution is, to shortcut the dependency on a width of `appWindow.contentItem`, as the final value is available from the start, in the property **`appWindow.width`**.

Let's see another example:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true
    Rectangle {
        id: someRect
        width: parent.width * 0.7 // depends on appWindow.contentItem.width -> initally 0, changing soon after
        heigth: appWindow.height * 0.7 // depends on appWindow.height -> initially 400.
        Component.onCompleted: console.log('someRect:', width, height) // prints: "someRect: 0 280"
        Rectangle {
            id: someOtherRect
            width: parent.width * 0.7  // depends on someRect.width which is initally 0 as it depends on appWindow.contentItem.width
            height: parent.height * 0.7 // depends on someRect.height which is initally 400 * 0.7
            Component.onCompleted: console.log('someOtherRect:', width, height) // prints "someOtherRect: 0, 196"
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the height will be set right from the start, while the width will change only as soon as `appWindow.contentItem` is being resized. So it is better to follow the way, I used for the `height`.

> There are many QML Components, where the parent might not be, what it seems. For custom Components that are, e.g. all Components that use `default property alias` to push "children" into nested `Item`s.

Comment: I missed some code while adding.I have edited my question please check.

Comment: Thanks .So  how to get the width ? One alternative is to create a component on onWidthChanged. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Yeah - use the `id` instead of `parent` - just as @dtech and I have written from the beginning.

Comment: `appWindow.width` is your value from the beginning. `parent.width` (which is `appWindow.contentItem.width`) is not.

Answer (score 2):

The `parent` of items, nested directly in the window is not the window, but the window's `contentItem`.

Try this instead:

```
Rectangle{
       id:rect
       width: appWindow.width * 0.75
       height: appWindow.height * 0.70
}
```

The same applies for your "full code":

```
Rectangle{
        id:rectParent
        width:appWindow.width * 0.75
        height: appWindow.height * 0.70
        Rectangle{
            id:rectChild
            width:parent.width * 0.75
            height: parent.height * 0.70
            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("Width=",width) //prints "Width= 337.5"
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use `parent` in the second rectangle, because its parent will be the first rectangle, but since the first is nested inside the window, it needs to refer to the window instead of its parent to get property sized.

Comment: there is no change. I am getting 0.

Comment: Impossible, it should work like that. Try Build - run qmake, your changes are probably not being reflected. It prints `qml: Width= 450` for me.

Comment: sorry i missed some code while adding to the question.I have edited please check.

Comment: if the parent itself is a rectangle and I am trying to get width in `oncompleted` then i am having a problem. Anyway, the above works if the parent is application window !!! .Can you suggest for this use case ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It is simple, children of windows are automatically nested in content items, so if you want to size an item to a window, use the window id instead of `parent`. If the parent is another item other than window, then you can use `parent`. Also, you can always use the id if you so chose instead of the parent.

Comment: The parent won't be the `ApplicationWindow`. It can never be, as the parent is necessarily a `Item`, and `ApplicationWindow` is no `Item`